# Create DropDownList in view and pass value to controller - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I create a DropDownList with values 1-10(int) in view and pass on the selected value to controller?

**UserReview model:**

```
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ReviewId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Rating { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
        public ActionResult Rating(Guid id) //got its ReviewId from previous page
        {
            //so far empty, no clue what to do    

            return Content("");
        }
```

Comment: To create the SelectList, you can use `var options = new SelectList(IEnumerable.Range(1, 10));` and pass it to the view. You need to show your model and the controller methods (what have you tried)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated the question with model. I tried to add your `var options =..`, but `Range` symbol couldn't be resolved.

Comment: Your model needs both a property to bind to (the selected value) say `int SelectedRating` and a property for the `SelectList` say `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RatingList` and you set the value of `RatingList` as per the code in my first comment. And then in the view its simply `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRating, Model.RatingList)`

Comment: Oops, sorry that's `Enumerable.Range()` (not `IEnumerable.Range()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Would you mind demonstrate with my code? I tried your solution but failed. I'll update the changes I tried.

Comment: What failed? (I will create a DotNetFiddle for you shortly to prove it works)

Comment: Based on your edit - in the GET method - `var model = new UserToReview(){ RatingList = options, ReviewId = id }; return View(model);` is all you need.

Comment: @StephenMuecke No I didn't meant your solution failed, I failed to make your solution work (just started to learn about MVC). I just updated my code in question.

Comment: Aah thanks for the example, hopefully I won't mess up this time :) I rolled back the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)First Method**
   In View

```
<select name="YourDropDownValue">
 @for(int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++) 
     {
  <option value="@i">@i</option>
     }
</select>
```

try using this code, In name attribute you have to keep the field name which you want to pass in the controller

In controller this is how you bind dropdown value

```
   [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult getDropDown(int YourDropDownValue)
  {


  }
```

**2)Second Method** 
Keep this in the controller get

```
  List<int> Num = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
  ViewBag.Number = new SelectList(Num);
```

Now in view

```
      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.YourDropDownValue, ViewBag.Number as SelectList)
```

if you have no model

```
      @Html.DropDownList("YourDropDownValue", ViewBag.Number as SelectList)
```

Now in Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult getDropDown(int YourDropDownValue)
  {


  }
```

Comment: The "MVC" way to do it would be to create the collection in the model rather then the view.

Comment: hmm.. This is so embarrassing, I know your solution is great, but I'm so bad at MVC that I can't make it work ( started 4 days ago). With the first method I could see the dropdownlist. But I don't know how to **send** the selected value to method `getDropDown(int YourDropDownValue)`. I also tried to  display the selected value by returning `Content(YourDropDownValue.ToString());`. The method 2 is way out of my league.

Comment: This solution is NOT great. Its bad practice and does not even give correct 2-way model binding.

Comment: @skylake the `List<int> Num = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };` which I kept in controller can also be kept in model repository class and then call that method in the controller

In repository class create a method  `public list<int> NumbersList() {
List<int> Num = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
return Num;
}`
And then in controller directly call this function, first create the instance of class in which function exists e.g repository and then call it

`ViewBag.Number = new SelectList(repository.NumbersList);` 
rest remains the same.